# psql generate_series method doesn't support concat inside

Tags: sql, postgresql, concatenation, generate-series

The following sql code worked as expected

```
generate_series('2018-06-29 00:00:00','2018-06-29 23:00:00', interval '1 hour')
```

but when I put concat method instead of first 2 parameters it's rise an error message

```
generate_series(concat('2018-06-29 00:00:00', '+05'), concat('2018-06-29 23:00:00', '+05'), interval '1 hour')
```

The error message

```
function generate_series(text, text, interval) does not exist
```

Comment: Could you please update your question title? All answers deal with timestamps and not the actual title. I came here from Google and it is a useless result for the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you concat it becomes as text data type. Hence you cannot generate series.

Below query will produce desired result

No need to write "interval". Since start and end are timestamp postgresql understands 5h and 1h are 5hours and 1hour

```
 select 
 generate_series(timestamp '2018-06-29 00:00:00' + '5h',
                 timestamp '2018-06-29 23:00:00' + '5h', 
                '1h')
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because `generate_series()` does not operate on strings.  Convert to the right data type:

```
select generate_series(concat('2018-06-29 00:00:00'::text, '+05'::text)::timestamp,
                       concat('2018-06-29 23:00:00'::text, '+05'::text)::timestamp,
                       interval '1 hour'
                      )
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for concat() or string operations.

If you want to add 5 hours to the start and ending timestamp, then just add that:

```
generate_series(timestamp '2018-06-29 00:00:00' + interval '5 hour',
                timestamp '2018-06-29 23:00:00' + interval '5 hour', interval '1 hour')
```